# PayPal Api Context

Tags: php, paypal

I am working  in [this](https://bedigit.com/item/laraclassified) script.  I am trying to use `use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;` code in my controller. I can't use `composer`.

In this regard How can I use PayPal ?

I am getting below error.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to believe you "can't use composer" as it looks like the project is using Laravel which has autoloading. Without proper autoloading set up, for this class to be found you'll have to add `require` statements to your project -- and you'll need to `require` each PayPal API source file so you don't get additional class not found errors. This is the "old" PHP way of doing things.

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php for documentation.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Butler. I am sorry. I couldn't express properly. Actually this script has a installer. I got this script from another developer. If I execute any `composer` command like `composer install` I am getting error. It is a confusing project to me. Did you use this script (https://bedigit.com/item/laraclassified/) ? I ran the project using Virtual Host not using `php artisan serve`. Could you please share some advise to work on this project ? Thanks.